# Random list generates as blocks not individual lines

Tags: python, loops, numbers

I am attempting to write a piece of code which does probability calculations based on the National lottery.
But I am having an issue with the way the code runs.
It prints out each one 5 times rather than creating a new set of random numbers, does anyone know why?

```
gen = True

while gen == True:

#Generate Numbers
a = random.randint(1,59)
b = random.randint(1,59)
c = random.randint(1,59)
d = random.randint(1,59)
e = random.randint(1,59)
f = random.randint(1,59)

#Create tickets as lists
ticket = []
balls = []

#print the tickets
for i in ticket:
    g = ticket[0]
    h = ticket[1]
    i = ticket[2]
    j = ticket[3]
    k = ticket[4]
    l = ticket[5]

for i in balls:
    m = balls[0]
    n = balls[1]
    o = balls[2]
    p = balls[3]
    q = balls[4]
    r = balls[5]


    print("TICKET")
    print(g,h,i,j,k,l)
    time.sleep(4)
    print("BALLS")
    print(m,n,o,p,q,r)
```

Thank you to anyone that can, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you have posted won't print anything because `ticket` and `balls` are empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understood the purpose of this program, However i saw you printed the `g,h,i,j,k,l` variables in the second loop, causing the last iteration values to be printed with the same value.

If the purpose is to print these values, place the ticket print in the tickets for loop:

```
for i in ticket:
    g = ticket[0]
    h = ticket[1]
    i = ticket[2]
    j = ticket[3]
    k = ticket[4]
    l = ticket[5]

    print("TICKET")
    print(g,h,i,j,k,l)

for i in balls:
    m = balls[0]
    n = balls[1]
    o = balls[2]
    p = balls[3]
    q = balls[4]
    r = balls[5]


    print("BALLS")
    print(m,n,o,p,q,r)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, that is very helpful. This is only part of the program, the purpose is to see how many times a lottery ticket has to be created before a ticket with matching numbers is generated. But thank you :)